# How to add output claim 'groups' from external AD provider in Azure AD B2C? (custom policy)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking for a way to add output claim 'groups' from external active directory provider to the azure ad b2c using custom policy.

I've added provider using [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom), but I can't add a custom claim.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you are wanting to save the `groups` claim from the external AD to the user object in the Azure AD B2C directory?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the groups the user belongs to in the token?